# Azure Function, how to upload/deliver the .NET/PS1 payload

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to create an Azure function in Terraform and obviously upload a test/sample code. So far I have got the below (copied off [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html)) but I dont know how to finish it off in terms of supply a payload for terraform to deliver into Azure for the actual function to work.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "azure-functions-cptest-rg"
  location = "westus2"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "test" {
  name                     = "functionsapptestsa"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location                 = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test" {
  name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  kind                = "FunctionApp"

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "test" {
  name                      = "test-azure-functions"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.test.id}"
  storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.test.primary_connection_string}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the terraform provider documentation this isnt possible yet to do natively. If you look at various examples online they upload code to the web apps (same deal, just more widespread) manually ([here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/terraform/terraform-slot-walkthru)). One thing you could do - is use FTP upload (terraform probably has ftp provider). But not sure you will be able to pull authentication data with terraform